# Setting defaults for properties in a class

Tags: php, class, oop

I need to write a class where users can set their own values if needed. I need to set default values to the properties.

How would I do this the correct way. Here is an example of what I need to achieve

```
class Test
{
    protected $var1;
    protected $var2;

    public function __construct($var1, $var2)
    {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
        $this->var2 = $var2;
    }

    public function setVar1($var1)
    {}

    public function getVar1()
    {}

    //etc
}
```

`$var1` should have a default value of `true` and `$var2` should be a text string, say `foo bar`. The user can set new his own values to `$var1` and `$var2`

How would I code these into the example above

Here is my thoughts

- defining the values in the constructor like `public function __construct($var1 = true, $var2  = 'foo bar')`
- or setting the values in the declaration of the properties like `protected $var1 = true;`

Comment: Okay, so what is the problem exactly? Your edit shows the possible answers already...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, It is just that I need to know, which is the more correct way. From the answers it does seem that I should go with  the first option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set default values for your method parameters. Note that that also makes them optional when you call your method:

```
public function __construct($var1 = true, $var2 = 'foo bar')
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Appreciate your help. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 2):

maybe u need something like this

```
  class Test
  {
  protected $var1;
  protected $var2;

  public function __construct($var1=true, $var2='foo bar')
  {
    $this->var1 = $var1;
    $this->var2 = $var2;
  }

  public function setVar1($var1)
  {
     $this->var1=$var1;
  }

  public function getVar1()
  {
     return $this->var1;
  }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you were beaten by seconds by the other one and it is just good sportmanship to accept that answer above yours. Unfortunately I can't upvote you yet as I need 15 reputation to do so. Thank for your help though, really appreciate it